# Why is my mango seed turning green but not sprouting?

Tags: indoors, germination, sprouting

I planted a mango seed six weeks ago, the seed itself turned green and it seems to me I can see a root forming down into the soil.

Yet after all this time there is no sprout coming up.

I'm a bit afraid to take it out of the soil and damaging the seed that way, while still thinking it might already be too late for the seed.

I am in a rather colder climate but the pot is on the radiator.
I have planted it directly in soil, I have kept the soil moist and there is no mold or anything.

Any tips on how to proceed with this or should I just accept the defeat?

Comment: Could we get a photo or two, ideally with what you suspect to be a root?

Comment: Not at home right now, I'll do it as soon as I can!

Comment: I have started a few. But only on a casual basis; I just buried the seeds in a garden. Months later I may find a strange weed , ie the mango. I guess half of them grow, then die when we get freezing temperatures .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Green just means that the seed has been accumulating the necessary amount of heat and light and air required to further germinate it forward.  you can germinate this sort of seed without putting into soil so you can keep any eye on the process, simply place the seed in some water along with some heat/light

Comment: So I could take the seed out of the soil and put it in a damp/wet paper towel to have it start germinating? Is this correct?

Comment: Taking the seed out know might not be the best solution, as you might damage a sprout if it has sprout, you could try to get it out very carefully and place the seed in a little bit of water yes, you can have it slightly submerged in the water alternatively I would suggest the next time you do it place it in the water.  you can place it on damp/wet towel but just don't let it dry out

Comment: I took the seed out of the dirt but it was dead, as I expected. Thank you for the help!

Comment: No problem, don't be disheartened just keep going till you succeed,